# Autocompleting XML values and attributes in Ace editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ace-editor

I'm looking to autocomplete XML tags and attributes. The valid values will come from the server. For example,

If I have a tag such as,

```
<status></status>
```

and my cursor is inside the open and closing tags, I'd like to hit `control + space` and have only valid values appear in the drop-down. Such as: `ok`, `error`, `warning`, ...

Similarly for attributes,

```
<status audience="">ok</status>
```

If my cursor has focus inside the quotes I'd like only valid audiences to appear in the drop-down when hitting `control + space`.

Here's what I have so far. This completer completes words I'm typing. I just can't figure out how to know what kind of tag I'm inside and how to send specific values for that tag or attribute.

Any ideas or examples to point me to? Thanks, /w

```
function loadEditor() {
    var langTools = ace.require("ace/ext/language_tools");
    editor = ace.edit("editor");
    editor.setOptions({
        enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
        enableLiveAutocompletion: true,
        enableSnippets: true,
    });
    editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/xml");

    var myCompleter = {
        getCompletions: function(editor, session, pos, prefix, callback) {
            if (prefix.length === 0) {
                callback(null, []);
                return;
            }                    
            $.getJSON("completions.php?a=completions&prefix=" 
                    + prefix + "&content=" + session, function(json) {
                callback(null, json.map(function(c) {
                    console.log("value: " + c.value);
                    return {value: c.value, caption: c.caption, meta: c.meta, score:c.score};
                }));
            })
        }
    };
    langTools.addCompleter(myCompleter);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The editors built-in tokeniser can be used to identify tag and attribute names.

```
var attributeCompleter = {
    getCompletions: function(editor, session, position, prefix, callback) {
        var results = [];

        var token = editor.session.getTokenAt(position.row, position.column);

        if (token.type === "string.attribute-value.xml") {
            var tokens = editor.session.getTokens(position.row);
            var tag, attribute;

            for (i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
                if (token.index <= tokens[i].index) {
                    break; // note tokens[i].index may be undefined
                }
                switch (tokens[i].type) {
                case "meta.tag.tag-name.xml":
                    tag = tokens[i];
                    break;
                case "entity.other.attribute-name.xml":
                    attribute = tokens[i];
                    break;
                }
            } // iteration has to be modified for xml tags divided over multiple lines
            
            if (tag.value === "status" && attribute.value === "audience") {
                results = [ { caption: "caption", value: "value", meta: "meta" } ];
            }
        }

        callback(null, results);
    }
};
```

Note that the tokeniser considers the ending citation `audience="example"`<- part of the attribute value.

Answer (score 1):

So far I haven't been able to find any projects with XML completion, so this is what I have implemented.

The `XhtmlTagInterpreter` has one function `getCompleteInfo()` that returns a JavaScript object of the form `{completeType: "attribute", tagName: "feline", attributeName: "breed"}`. In this example it would try to auto-complete the `breed` attribute of `<feline breed="" />`.

It sends that data to the server for the appropriate `breed` values. This service is up to you to implement. e.g. `https://www.example.com/services/mock/autocompleter/attribute.json?tagName=feline&attributeName=breed`

The JSON returned will be something like this.

```
[
    {"score":"1000","meta":"cats","caption":"siamese","value":"siamese"},
    {"score":"1000","meta":"cats","caption":"burmese","value":"burmese"},
    {"score":"1000","meta":"cats","caption":"bengal","value":"bengal"}
]
```

Here is the working JavaScript.

```
function XHtmlTagInterpreter(row, col, session) {
    "use strict";
    this.row = row;
    this.col = col;
    this.session = session;
    this.leftOfCursor = null;
    this.rightOfCursor = null;
    this.leftType = null;
    this.rightType = null;
}

/**
 * Sets the left of cursor property used by other methods. This is a
 * string without new lines from the beginning of the document to the
 * letter just before the cursor. 
 */
XHtmlTagInterpreter.prototype.setLeftOfCursor = function() {
    "use strict";
    this.leftOfCursor = "";
    for (var r=0; r<=this.row; r++) {
        if (r === this.row) {
            var line = this.session.getLine(r);
            for (var c=0; c<this.col; c++) {
                this.leftOfCursor += line[c];
            }
        } else {
            this.leftOfCursor += this.session.getLine(r);
        }
    }
};

/**
 * Sets the right of cursor property used by other methods. This is a
 * string without new lines from the letter just to the right of the cursor
 * to the end of the document. 
 */
XHtmlTagInterpreter.prototype.setRightOfCursor = function() {
    "use strict";
    this.rightOfCursor = "";
    for (var r=this.row; r<=this.session.getLength(); r++) {
        if (r === this.row) {
            var line = this.session.getLine(r);
            for (var c=this.col; c<line.length; c++) {
                this.rightOfCursor += line[c];
            }
        } else {
            this.rightOfCursor += this.session.getLine(r);
        }
    }
};

/**
 * Sets the left type depending on first non-whitespace character to the
 * left of the cursor position. We look for a right angle or a quotation.
 * If a right angle we assume the cursor is inside a tag. If quotation the
 * cursor is inside an attribute. We set the left type value to 'value'
 * or 'attribute'. 
 */
XHtmlTagInterpreter.prototype.setLeftType = function() {
    "use strict";
    this.setLeftOfCursor();
    if (this.leftOfCursor === undefined || this.leftOfCursor.length === 0) {
        this.leftType = ""; 
        return;
    }
    for (var i=this.leftOfCursor.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
        if (this.leftOfCursor[i] === " " || this.leftOfCursor[i] === "\t") {
            continue;
        }
        if (this.leftOfCursor[i] === ">") {
            this.leftType = "value";
            return;
        } else if (this.leftOfCursor[i] === '"') {
            this.leftType = "attribute";
            return;
        } else {
            this.leftType = "";
            return;
        }
    }
};

/**
 * Sets the right type depending on first non-whitespace character to the
 * right of the cursor position. We look for a left angle or a quotation.
 * If a left angle we assume the cursor is inside a tag. If quotation the
 * cursor is inside an attribute. We set the right type value to 'value'
 * or 'attribute'. 
 */
XHtmlTagInterpreter.prototype.setRightType = function() {
    "use strict";
    this.setRightOfCursor();
    if (this.rightOfCursor === undefined 
            || this.rightOfCursor.length === 0) {
        this.rightType = ""; 
        return;
    }
    for (var i=0; i<this.rightOfCursor.length; i++) {
        if (this.rightOfCursor[i] === " " 
                || this.rightOfCursor[i] === "\t") {
            continue;
        }
        if (this.rightOfCursor[i] === "<") {
            this.rightType = "value";
            return;
        } else if (this.rightOfCursor[i] === '"') {
            this.rightType = "attribute";
            return;
        } else {
            this.rightType = "";
            return;
        }
    }
};

/**
 * Returns the tag name to be sent to autocompleter service.
 * @returns {_L1.XHtmlTagInterpreter.prototype@pro;leftOfCursor@call;trim@call;replace|String}
 */
XHtmlTagInterpreter.prototype.getCompleteInfo = function() {
    "use strict";
    this.setLeftType();
    this.setRightType();
    if (this.leftType !== this.rightType) {
        return "";
    }
    if (this.leftType === "value") {
        var tagName = this.leftOfCursor.trim()
                .replace(new RegExp("^.*<([a-z:]+).*?>$"), "$1");
        return {completeType: "value", tagName: tagName};
    } else if (this.leftType === "attribute") {
        var tagName = this.leftOfCursor.trim()
                .replace(new RegExp("^.*<([a-z:]+).*?([a-z:]+)\s*=\s*\"$"), "$1");
        var attributeName = this.leftOfCursor.trim()
                .replace(new RegExp("^.*<([a-z:]+).*?([a-z:]+)\s*=\s*\"$"), "$2");
        return {completeType: "attribute", tagName: tagName, 
            attributeName: attributeName};
    } else {
        return null;
    }
};

var loadEditor = function(editor) {
    var chileCompleter = {
        getCompletions: function(editor, session, pos, prefix, callback) {
            if (prefix.length === 0) {
                var line = session.getLine(pos.row);
                if (undefined !== line) {
                    var interpreter = new XHtmlTagInterpreter(pos.row, 
                        pos.column, session);
                    var completeInfo = interpreter.getCompleteInfo();
                    if (undefined === completeInfo || completeInfo === null 
                            || undefined === completeInfo.completeType 
                            || completeInfo.completeType === null
                            || completeInfo.completeType.length === 0
                            || undefined === completeInfo.tagName 
                            || completeInfo.tagName === null
                            || completeInfo.tagName.length === 0) {
                        callback(null, []);
                        return;
                    }

                    $.getJSON(chileContextPath 
                            + "services/mock/autocompleter/" 
                            + encodeURIComponent(completeInfo.completeType) 
                            + ".json?tagName=" 
                            + encodeURIComponent(completeInfo.tagName) 
                            + "&attributeName=" 
                            + encodeURIComponent(completeInfo.attributeName), 
                            function(json) {
                        callback(null, json.content.map(function(c) {
                            return {value: c.value, caption: c.caption, 
                                meta: c.meta, score:c.score};
                        }));
                    })
                }
            } else {
                callback(null, []);
                return;
            }
        }
    };

    editor = ace.edit("chile-editor");
    editor.setOptions({
        enableBasicAutocompletion: [chileCompleter],
        enableLiveAutocompletion: true,
        enableSnippets: true,
    });
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/clouds");
    editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/xml");
    editor.getSession().setUseWrapMode(true);
    editor = loadXKbml(editor);

    return editor;
};
```